# Manipulate[] inside DialogInput[]

Tags: manipulate

I would like to get input from an interactive dialog that uses `Manipulate[]`. But I find that my `Manipulate[]` breaks when I put it inside a `DialogInput[]`.  So, when I try `DialogInput[Manipulate[Plot[Sin[e x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {e, 1, 10}]]` the plot inside the dialog is not connected to the `Manipulate[]` slider.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using global variables. Return the value with `DialogReturn`.

```
res = DialogInput[{
         TextCell["Set value of e. Then click Proceed."],
         Manipulate[Plot[Sin[e x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {e, 1, 10, 
              Appearance -> "Open" }, 
         LocalizeVariables -> False], 
         Button["Proceed", DialogReturn[e]]
                 }]
```

[image: DialogInput]

Comment: Nice.  This may be the first practical use I've seen of `LocalizeVariables -> False`.