# Manipulate not working inside DialogInput

Tags: manipulate

Some controls do not appear to work with `Manipulate` inside a `DialogInput`. For example:

```
DialogInput[{Manipulate[x, {x, {1, 2, 3}}], DefaultButton[]}]
```

does not work, but the slider version:

```
DialogInput[{Manipulate[x, {x, 1, 3, 1}], DefaultButton[]}]
```

does work.

Is this a bug or am I missing a vital option setting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
DialogInput[{Manipulate[Dynamic[x], {{x, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, 
   LocalizeVariables -> False], Button["OK", DialogReturn[x]]}]
```

I'm not sure why `Dynamic` is required.

`LocalizeVariables -> False` allows the value of `x` to be returned (outside of the scope of the `Manipulate`.  `LocalizedVariables` was shown to be necessary for a `Manipulate` embedded in `DialogInput`. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/manipulate-inside-dialoginput/2114#2114).

Comment: Do you know why that additional `Dyanmic` is required only in this case?

Comment: No. I haven't a clue.

Comment: Thank you so much David, this has been driving me nuts.

Comment: @Simon Glad to be of help. I still find it strange that `Manipulate[x, {{x, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}]` works fine by itself, with x behaving like a dynamic variable within `Manipulate` when `Manipulate is not embedded in `DialogInput`.