# Problems with manipulating plot in a dialog

Tags: manipulate, dialog-window

G'day, guys. Here is a silly problem I am struggling with.

```
(*file name: 1.nb*)Button["Load the program", NotebookEvaluate[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]], Method->"Queued"]

(*file name: 2.nb*)eff = 1 - y Abs[1 + x]/(2 + Abs[1 + x]);CreateWindow[DialogNotebook[{TabView[{"eff"->Panel[With[{expr = eff}, Manipulate[Plot[expr, {x, -5, 5}], {y, 0, 0.1, 0.001}]]]}]
```

The 2 lines of codes are saved in separate file. The idea is that I want to use the first file to open the 2nd file and show the manipulate output in a dialog. The 2nd file runs fine with itself from notebook (i.e. output shows fine in notbook and a dialog window). However, if I choose the 2nd file by running the 1st file, the graph doesn't update dynamically.
Anyone got an idea for that? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This sounds really related to a question I recently posted. It may be that the solution for mine will help you as well.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43134/why-do-inputfields-not-respond-in-manipulate-utilizing-findgeometrictransform